# Small Business Server Standard 2011 Acting As A Router/Firewall or Connected Via Switch

Tags: switch, windows-sbs, route

Using Small Business Server Standard 2011, what is the preferred best practice for a group of about 15 computers.

To use it as the router/firewall and have it be assigning DHCP, or have it connected with the rest of the network via a switch?

Comment: Using the server as a router/firewall and using it as a DHCP server are two different functions. The default install of SBS will install and configure the DHCP role. My preference would be to use a dedicated hardware firewall/router and leave those functions off of the SBS server.

Comment: So basically have it looking like this? http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC461694.gif

Comment: Yes, that's the way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

SBS 2003 used to ship with ISA Server which would allow you to use the SBS box as a firewall/gateway.

It is no longer supported to have SBS 2018 or SBS 2011 as an edge device. Thus your only option is to have the SBS sit on the network like a normal server would and have something *else* provide your internet connection.

The internet device can be "dumb" - in that you don't need to use its DHCP or WiFi, you can still (and should) have SBS serve your DHCP requests.